# Implementing Multi-Label Margin-Loss in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm wanted to implement the Multi-Label Margin-Loss in Tensorflow, using as orientation the definition of pytorch, i.e.

[image: Example]

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiLabelMarginLoss.html

This is the naive solution I came up with:

```
def naive(y_true, y_pred, mu = 1.0):
    pos = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.bool))
    neg = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.cast(1 - y_true, dtype=tf.bool))

    loss = 0
    for i in range(y_true.shape[0]):
        loss += tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.relu(mu - (tf.transpose([pos[i]]) - neg[i])))
    return loss
```

The implementation above yield correct results (see example below), but I'm having a hard time removing the loop from the function, i.e. expressing this in matrix/vector multiplication, etc.

Example:

```
y_pred = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8]], dtype=tf.float32)
print(y_pred)

y_true = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
print(y_true)

naive(y_true, y_pred)

# 0.25 * ((1-(0.1-0.2)) + (1-(0.1-0.4)) + (1-(0.8-0.2)) + (1-(0.8-0.4)))
# 0.8500

# (see pytorch example)
```

Any ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Besides the fact that you are using a for loop, are the results correct?

Comment: @AloneTogether Yes the results are correct, I've added an example to the question.

Comment: But why exactly do you need a loop?

Comment: @AloneTogether I don't. My goal is to get rid of the loop and express the entire loss function using efficient numpy/tensorflow expressions such as matrix-vector-multiplication, broadcasting, etc. to speed up the loss computation when training a NN model.

Comment: @AloneTogether The first dimension of the inputs `y_true` and `y_pred` corresponds to batch dimension, so multiple samples stacked on top of each other. In my implementation, the function loops over the batch dimension to process each sample individually. (Indeed, in the example above the batch only contains one sample, i.e. the input shapes are `(1, 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `tf.while_loop` like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def naive(y_true, y_pred, mu = 1.0):
    pos = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.bool))
    neg = tf.ragged.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.cast(1 - y_true, dtype=tf.bool))
    
    loss = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
    i = tf.constant(0)    
    while_condition = lambda i, loss, pos, neg: tf.math.less(i, tf.shape(y_true)[0])

    def body(i, loss, p, n):
      loss.assign_add(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.relu(1.0 - (tf.transpose([p[i]]) - n[i]))))
      return tf.add(i, 1), loss, p, n

    _, loss, _,_ = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, loop_vars=(i, loss, pos, neg))

    return loss

y_pred = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8], [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_true = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
naive(y_true, y_pred)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=1.7>
```